# Sqoop Export to SQL Server - allow insert mode

Tags: sql-server, sqoop

I am trying to sqoop export data to SQL Server with --update-mode as 'allowinsert' and getting below error :

```
 Error during export: Mixed update/insert is not supported against the target database yet
```

Has anyone faced this error with SQL server and is there any version of SQL Server which supports *upsert* operation through SQOOP. The Sqoop version I am using is 1.4.6

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue. The feature is simply not supported in Sqoop 1.4.6 (for SQL Server that is). The best way to do so is, if possible, upgrade Sqoop to version 2.
In my case that is not possible, so I have to perform two sqoop jobs: one for inserting and one for updating.

If someone have a better way of doing that, please feel free to share!

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be working with the following combination:
Sqoop 1.4.6.2.6.5.0-292 and SQL Server 13.0.5026.0 (SQL Server 2016). But I'm not sure that it's working because of the specific combination, rather than specific settings on the SQL server OR this specific version of Sqoop.